# Django 1.11.20 get count of rows per ISO week and year

Tags: python, django

I need to get the count of items per ISO week and year. I tried the following

```
    from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeek, ExtractYear
    from django.db.models.aggregates import Count

    count = myModel.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear('created_at')) \
        .annotate(week=ExtractWeek('created_at')) \
        .values('year','week') \
        .annotate(count=Count('week'))
```

But my result is

```
<QuerySet [{'year': 2019, 'week': 7, 'count': 1}, {'year': 2019, 'week': 7, 'count': 1}, {'year': 2019, 'week': 7, 'count': 1}, {'year': 2019, 'week': 7, 'count': 1}.......
```

How can I get change it so my result is:

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show model

Comment: The model is a bit large, but you can assume it has a 'id' and 'created_at' fields

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not the missing `order_by` but likely the opposite: a default `order_by` presumably present in `myModel` by way of an `ordering` field specifying a default sort, which added another field to the query that sabotaged your grouping. The relevant Django doc is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#s-interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by).

You can get rid of it by appending `.order_by()` to the query or you can specify a different ordering like you did in your answer.

This is a snag that gets people again and again (myself included) so I prefer not to use default sorting in models.

PS: When things aren't running to plan, it often helps to inspect the generated SQL by either checking the last executed query:

```
django.db.connection.queries[-1]
```

... or by asking for the SQL of a query you've just defined:

```
str(my_query.query)
```

And if you like what you see but don't like the way the SQL is (not) formatted, look into [sqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TruncWeek` and `TruncYear`:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncWeek, TruncYear

count_for_week = myModel.objects.annotate(
    week=TruncWeek('created_at'),
).values(
    'week',
).annotate(
    count=Count('id'),
)

count_for_year = myModel.objects.annotate(
    year=TruncYear('created_at'),
).values(
    'year',
).annotate(
    count=Count('id'),
)
```

As as result you will have:

```
 <QuerySet [{'week': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}]>
```

Where `week` or `year` values will be a begin datetime for that range: week of year

More details you can read in Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#datefield-truncation).

Comment: I tried your solution but I keep getting {'week': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1} in my result. The count doesn't go above 1

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I forgot to order the result

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeek, ExtractYear
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count

count = myModel.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear('created_at')) \
    .annotate(week=ExtractWeek('created_at')) \
    .values('year','week') \
    .annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('count')

<QuerySet [{'year': 2019, 'week': 7, 'count': 8}]>
```